# Extract URL from a td field in HTML

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I want to extract from a HTML string all URLs like below using Nokogiri.

```
<td width="101" style="background: url(https://www.someurl.com/images/images.jpg) no-repeat top left #f9f9f9; text-align:center;">
```

Result should be

```
["https://www.someurl.com/images/images.jpg"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
doc.css('td[style]').map { |n|
  n["style"][/background:[^};]*\burl\s*\(\s*(.*?)(?<!\\)\s*\)/, 1]
}.compact
```

Explanation:

- pick out all `td` elements that have `style` attribute
- for each one, try to extract the url by taking the first capture group of the regexp
- eliminate `nil` results (i.e. those which failed the regexp)

The regexp is a bit funky, but basically:

- look for `background:` and then anything as long as it isn't a semicolon or a closing brace, because that would end the rule
- after that, we want `url(...)` but not as a part of a bigger word, thus `\b` word-boundary
- inside the parentheses, we want to capture everything up to the first closing parenthesis that is not escaped by a backslash.

It still does not handle the case where the URL is quoted (`url("http://example.com")`); it should capture the whole thing, together with quotes, so you'll have to strip them yourself (or toy around with regexp a bit more).

Comment: Thanks a lot . Can you plz answer one more question . I have one more scenario where I want to replace the url , so the output will be like td width="101" style="background: url(https://www.newurlsomeurl.com/images/images.jpg) no-repeat top left #f9f9f9; text-align:center;">

Comment: This is hard to answer without knowing what you want to replace into what.

Answer (score 0):

If the target is *only* in table cells with `style` parameters, then it is easy:

```
require 'nokogiri'

html = '<td width="101" style="background: url(https://www.someurl.com/images/images.jpg) no-repeat top left #f9f9f9; text-align:center;">'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)

doc.search('td[style*="url("]').map{ |td|
  td['style'][/url\((.+?)\)/, 1]
} # => ["https://www.someurl.com/images/images.jpg"]
```

If it's in any tag with the `style` parameter which contains `url`, it's a minor change to the CSS selector: `'*[style*="url("]'`. If it's in several specific tags then it's still doable, but I'll leave that up to you to figure out.